# Compile error in rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp

When I compile the code below in Rcpp, I get the following error in the file named stl_algobase.h:

```
`no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >'`
```

I'm using standard type declarations so I'm not clear where the value type is incorrect.

Here's the code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <cstddef>   // std:size_t
#include <iterator>  // std:begin, std::end
#include <vector>    // std::vector
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
    bool dupCheckRcpp (const Rcpp::NumericVector vec, const Rcpp::NumericMatrix allMatrix) {
    int i, nrow, ncol;
    bool flag;
    nrow = allMatrix.nrow(); ncol = allMatrix.ncol();
    Rcpp::NumericVector vecTmp(ncol);

    flag = false;
    for (i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
      // copy to vector
      vecTmp = allMatrix[i];
      // compare
        if (std::equal(vec.begin(),vec.end(),vecTmp)) {
          flag = true;
          return flag;
          }
    }
    return flag; 
  }
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `std::equal` you need to pass iterators, not the whole container. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal

change

```
if (std::equal(vec.begin(),vec.end(),vecTmp)) {
```

to

```
if (std::equal(vec.begin(),vec.end(),vecTmp.begin())) {
```

Comment: That helped, but I also had to fix the environment variable by executing the following R code:  
        
        `Sys.setenv(PATH="%PATH%;C:/RBuildTools/bin;C:/RBuildTools/gcc-4.6.3/bin")`